# SharePoint Online Management Shell - PowerShell - Set-SPOSiteGroup - update SharePoint Group permissions for subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions

I migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint Online with a 3rd party tool - background knowledge.
The Security Group was in a local domain.  I found an equivalent SharePoint Group group that I would like to use.
I have a few 100+ sites and PowerShell will help.  Sadly they are SUBSITES within ONE Site Collection.
Again, we are migrating so it is a step to promote them to their own Site Collections.

I tested with

```
Set-SPOSiteGroup -Site "https://TenantDomain.SharePoint.com/sites/SiteCollectionName" -Identity "SharePoint Group Name" -PermissionLevelToAdd "Read"
```

this works FINE with the site collection, now when I put in /ABC I get

> Set-SPOSiteGroup : The managed path sites/SiteCollectionName is not a
> managed path in this tenant.

In the management shell, I clicked the up arrow in my keyboard and appended the line that JUST worked and was working for the site collection.  I want to set it on some subsites that have broken inheritance / unique permissions for each subsite.
I just added that /ABC (no / at the end).  Is there a different PowerShell command to run, etc.?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `Set-SPOSiteGroup` is expecting a site collection address. You may want to try `Set-PnPGroupPermissions` instead.

You can either connect the subsite directly using `Connect-PnPOnline` or you can use the `Web` parameter on `Set-PnPGroupPermissions` to specify the subsite. More information can be found here:

- [Set-PnPGroupPermissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpgrouppermissions?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973&view=sharepoint-ps)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Set-SPOSiteGroup updates the SharePoint Online owner and permission levels on a group inside a site collection.

You could execute the following Powershell script:

```
#connect to subsite
$SiteURL= "https://test.spo.com/sites/projects/it"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

#set permissions of a specific SharePoint group
Set-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity 'Echo Members' -RemoveRole 'Edit' -AddRole 'Read'
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]

——————————————————**Updated Answer**—————————————————

You can execute the following script to replace the original script.

```
#connect to subsite
$SiteURL= "https://test.spo.com/sites/projects/it"
$username = "name@test.xxx.com"
$credential = Get-Credential -UserName $username -Message "Type the password:"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $credential

#set permissions of a specific SharePoint group
Set-PnPGroupPermissions -Identity 'Echo Members' -RemoveRole 'Edit' -AddRole 'Read'
```

—————————————————— **`Updated Answer`** ————————————————

Basically it’s just not going to authenticate you because of **MFA**. To resolve this issue, use the **-UseWebLogin** parameter.

**Your screen should look like this:**

```
$SiteURL= "https://test.spo.com/sites/projects/it"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -UseWebLogin
```

Comment: Hi, Matt Carter. I have updated the answer under original My Answer. Hope this helps you. I wish you all the best!

Comment: Thank you!  It works!  Now I am just being greedy!    I have a list of about 100+ sites.  Same SharePoint Group name and same permission level.  Is there a way to scroll through without putting in MFA more than at the beginning?  I am SPO Admin.

Comment: Hi, Matt Carter. I have updated the answer under original My Answer. Have a nice day!